# Scraping some Facebook data but not all? Scrapy/Splash/Python

Tags: python, facebook, scrapy, splash-screen

I have a spider that looks like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class BarkbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'barkbot'
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.facebook.com/pg/TheBarkFL/events/?ref=page_internal/'
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'output/barkoutput.json'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url,
                self.parse,
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("div#upcoming_events_card a::attr(href)").extract():
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_concert)

    def parse_concert(self, response):
        concert = {

            "headliner" : response.xpath(
                "//h1[@id='seo_h1_tag']/text()"
            ).extract_first(),

            "venue" : "The Bark",
            "venue_address" : "507 All Saints St.",
            "venue_website" : "https://www.facebook.com/TheBarkFL",

            "date_time" : response.xpath(
                "//li[@id='event_time_info']//text()"
            ).extract(),

            "notes" : response.xpath(
                "//div[@data-testid='event-permalink-details']/span/text()"
            ).extract()

        }

        if concert['headliner']:
            yield concert
```

I run the spider and it finishes successfully. But all the "notes" and "date_time" keys are returning is empty lists. I'm especially confused on the notes one, as that seems fairly straightforward unless xpath can't use data-testid as an attribute. I am, however, getting the headliner key successfully scraped, so I'm obviously connecting to each page.

I'm new to scraping JavaScript-generated content and thus Splash, but I've managed to get one other spider working successfully, just not on Facebook. What gives?

Comment: Does Splash give you access to the network requests that the browser makes? Because pulling the event data out of their XHR call to the graphql endpoint would be amazing, since it's structured data

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, so don´t do that. you must use the api.

Answer (score 1):

> unless xpath can't use data-testid as an attribute

No, that's not it; I just checked with Scrapy 1.5.1 and your xpath matched a sample document fine. It even matched the other `data-testid` attributes in that document, so I am pretty sure you've hit a race condition because `event-permalink-details` does not appear in the HTML; it's loaded from an XHR call to their graphql endpoint. Which in your case may be fine due to Splash, but if your selector isn't matching, then that selector is running before the XHR has resolved. I don't know enough Splash to help troubleshoot that situation.

---

I don't know the answer to your `date_time` question, but I actually bet what you really want is `.xpath('//li[@id="event_time_info"]//@content')` because that contains `2019-01-03T17:30:00-08:00 to 2019-01-03T20:30:00-08:00` which seems much nicer than the blob of strings the unqualified `text()` matches